# Invalid Json from Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a problem with returning a json object from a REST method in Oracle Apex. Apex puts an escape character in front of every quotation mark and hence the json object is returned as a string.

The database procedure is defined as taking three parameters. One in and two out where the first out is a Json returned as a clob and the other as varchar2.

```sql
dbProcedure(paymentid in varchar2, paymentKeys out clob, message out varchar2)
```

If I call the procedure, using a pl/sql script in SQL Developer, I get a correctly defined json. However if I call the procedure from Apex I get the json with escape characters for the quotation marks.

The PL/SQL procedure call (in SQL Developer) returns:

```json
{"PaymentKeys":[{"PaymentKey":"00000084","InvoiceId":5000119,"InvoiceNumber":"94500502","A_P-t ...
```

and, using Postman, the Apex Rest call returns:

```json
{"keyvalues":"{\"PaymentKeys\":[{\"PaymentKey\":\"00000084\",\"InvoiceId\":\"\\\"5000119\\\"\",\"InvoiceNumber\":\"94500502\",\"A_P- ...
```

The REST method is defined in APEX as:
Method: GET
Source Type: PL/SQL
Format: JSON
Parameters: first IN as HTTP HEADER and the two OUT as type RESPONSE.

```sql
begin
   dbProcedure(:paymentid, :paymentKeys, :message);
end;
```

I can see that if I change the **Source Type** in the Rest method to be of type **HTTP HEADER** I get the correct result from the procedure, that is a valid Json. However by setting the **Sourse Type** to **RESPONSE** I get the invalid Json. So this seems to be some Apex feature. (The consumer of the rest method asked to get a RESPONSE rather than a HTTP HEADER.)

I have now tried to define it as a single parameter REST. Defined a function in the database returning a clob with the REST parameter being a IN/OUT, *Access Method*, and the *Source Type* as HTTP HEADER. This also produces the correct result.

How do I get Apex to return the correct result, a valid json?

*Product versions*:
Apex 19.1.0.00.15
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0
Postman 9.15.0
SQL Developer 21.4.2.018

Comment: Have you tested the REST get using a tool like Postman? This will tell you if the problem is in the definition of the REST api, with the data it is getting, or with the method you're currently using to call it.

Comment: Yes I used Postman to request the REST method. What do you mean with "... if the problem is in the definition of the REST api, with the data it is getting, or with the method you're currently using ..."?

Comment: That was just to check that the response was being escaped by the REST API and not something in the tool you were using to read the response.

Comment: Can you provide details of the config of your REST endpoint? I wasn't expecting you would have any out variable of type RESPONSE at all. Does your procedure output the response using `htp.p()`?

Comment: There is no use of htp.p in the procedure or function. The procedure builds a json_object_t and returns it as a clob (json_obj.to_clob). Is this clear enough?

Comment: I can see that on your, impressive, web page you have a block under *Pretty Print JSON in PL/SQL* that uses json_object_t. Is that a anonymous block in APEX?

Comment: I added your **Pretty Print** function to the database package and used it to format the result and now APEX returns it as `{"result": "{\n  \"PaymentKeys\" :\n  [\n    {\n      \"PaymentKey\" : \"00000084\",\n      \"InvoiceId\"` Now newline is escaped as well.
The call in SQL Developer returns a pretty printed json :-)

Comment: In this case pretty printing is not relevant. I don't know if using a RESPONSE type is needed, in my case I just send the response via htp.p and that's it.

Comment: Yes, pretty print is not relevant, it was just as a supplement to show that APEX is converting json to json by escaping the json input.

Comment: Jeff Smith (ThatJeffSmith) has a post on this https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/ords-returning-raw-json/ and it seems that htp.p is the way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Smith (ThatJeffSmith) has a post on this [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/ords-returning-raw-json) and it seems that htp.p is the way out.
The solution that I chose was to use htp.p.